# Somar valores depois de um separador

Tags: javascript

Como não sei muito de javascript gostaria de uma ajudinha para resolver esse meu problema
Nesse script abaixo tenho que fazer o calculo pegando só os últimos dígitos separados pelo hífen -

```
value="10-banana-2,55" ==> só somar o  ( 2,55 ) depois do segundo traço 

id-nome-valor
```

```js
$(function() {
  total = document.getElementById('total');
  $(document.getElementsByName('choice')).bind('click', function() {

    var valTotal = total.value;

    valTotal = parseFloat(valTotal.replace(',', '.'));

    var valInput = (this.value);

    valInput = parseFloat(valInput.replace(',', '.'));

    var novoTotal = 0;
    var value = (this.checked) ? parseFloat((valTotal + valInput)).toFixed(2) : parseFloat((valTotal - valInput)).toFixed(2);
    total.value = value.replace('.', ',');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form name="listForm" id="listForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="10-banana-2,55" />2,55<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="12-uva-3,00" />3,00<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="13-pera-1,00" />1,00<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="16-tmate-2,00" />2,00<br/>
  <input type="text" size="4" name="total" id="total" value="100,00" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando o seu script, para não complicar muito e você entender o que se passar, pode fazer assim

```
$(function() {
        total = document.getElementById('total');

        $(document.getElementsByName('choice')).bind('click', function() {

            var valTotal = total.value;

            valTotal = parseFloat(valTotal.replace(',', '.'));

            // Pega o valor selecionado e divide pelo '-', o resultado do split gera um array
            var valInput_split = (this.value).split('-');

            // Pega o último valor deste array, que no seu caso é o valor que você quer somar
            var valor_final = valInput_split[valInput_split.length-1];

            var valInput = parseFloat(valor_final.replace(',', '.'));

            var novoTotal = 0;
            var value = (this.checked) ? parseFloat((valTotal + valInput)).toFixed(2) : parseFloat((valTotal - valInput)).toFixed(2);
            total.value = value.replace('.', ',');
        });

    });
```

Em resumo basta troca restas duas linhas

```
var valInput = (this.value);
valInput = parseFloat(valInput.replace(',', '.'));
```

Por estas três linhas

```
var valInput_split = (this.value).split('-');
var valor_final = valInput_split[valInput_split.length-1];
var valInput = parseFloat(valor_final.replace(',', '.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Tens de partir esse valor em pedaços mas também converter Strings `2,55` em Numeros com `.`.

Sugestão:

```js
$(function() {
  function converterNumero(nr) {
    if (typeof nr === 'number') return nr;
    return Number(nr.replace(',', '.'));
  }

  var total = $('#total');
  var escolhas = $('[name="choice"]');
  escolhas.on('change', function() {

    var soma = escolhas.get().reduce(function(soma, el) {
      if (!el.checked) return soma;
      var nr = el.value.split('-').pop();
      var value = converterNumero(nr);

      return soma + value;
    }, Number(converterNumero(total.val())));
    total.val(soma);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form name="listForm" id="listForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="10-banana-2,55" />2,55<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="12-uva-3,00" />3,00<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="13-pera-1,00" />1,00<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="16-tmate-2,00" />2,00<br/>
  <input type="text" size="4" name="total" id="total" value="100,00" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Não use mais `.bind` porque ele se tornou obsoleto desde a [versão 1.7
>   do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) e foi removido da versão 3.0.

Uma sugestão para pegar o valor é usar o método [.substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr). Basta usar como argumento único o `.lastIndexOf("-")+1`, ou seja, irá pegar o primeiro caractere após o último hífen até o final da string.

No exemplo abaixo substituí alguns métodos JS puro por métodos jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
   var total = $('#total');
  $('[name=choice]').on('click', function(){

    var valTotal = total.val();

    valTotal = parseFloat(valTotal.replace(',', '.'));

    var valInput = this.value.substr(this.value.lastIndexOf("-")+1);

    valInput = parseFloat(valInput.replace(',', '.'));

    var novoTotal = 0;
    var value = (this.checked) ? parseFloat((valTotal + valInput)).toFixed(2) : parseFloat((valTotal - valInput)).toFixed(2);
    total.val(value.replace('.', ','));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="listForm" id="listForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="10-banana-2,55" />2,55<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="12-uva-3,00" />3,00<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="13-pera-1,00" />1,00<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="16-tmate-2,00" />2,00<br/>
  <input type="text" size="4" name="total" id="total" value="100,00" />
</form>
```